# Python 3: subprocess, changing directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a main project in `C:/myproject/harry.py`

harry.py is launching threads.

harry.py is saving and loading text documents every few seconds using an already established path `self.relativePath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`

Inside each thread, a subprocess is being called to activate a command line .exe file found in `C:/myproject/betty/here.exe`

I have tried all sorts of things to achieve this such as:

```
my_env = os.environ
my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"]
doit = subprocess.Popen('cd betty/', 'here.exe -command', env=my_env)
doit.wait()
```

or

```
my_env = os.environ
my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"]
doit = subprocess.Popen('here.exe -command', cwd='C:/myproject/betty/')
doit.wait()
```

Response:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Is it possible to run the subprocess inside the subfolder with the custom path ... that will not interfere with the already established path `self.relativePath`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer with some help from various stackoverflow posts on the topic as well as stumbling through possible solutions. It was not easy!

```
self.relativePath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

self.relativePath1 = self.relativePath + '\\your_subdirectoryHERE\\'
```

Be sure to include double slashes, to match os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.relativePath1 + 'flare.exe -command', cwd=self.relativePath1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You were fairly close:

```
> doit = subprocess.Popen('here.exe -command', cwd='C:/myproject/betty/')
```

This would actually work if your command were called `here.exe -command` but of course, no such file exists. You want `['here.exe', '-command']` (or somewhat more unsafely and less efficiently add `shell=True`; but really, don't).

It seems you forgot to pass in `env=my_env` in this attempt, too; though does `here.exe` really require you to modify the `PATH`? And if it does, repeatedly creating a new copy for each new subprocess seems slightly wasteful.

You'll also want to switch to `subprocess.run()` or one of the legacy wrappers; you should really only use the low-level `Popen()` function directly from library functions.

On the other hand, does `here.exe` really need to run in a particular directory, and does that directory exist on your `PATH`? Windows is slightly weird and Windows programmers are often unaware of basic command-line usability design principles; but if `here.exe` is at all correctly written, perhaps you are actually looking for

```
s = subprocess.run(['c:/myproject/betty/here.exe', '-command'], env=my_env)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not very familiar with os.environ generally... or subprocesses. I'll test your example in a few hours. Thanks!

Comment: Hi tripleee, when I run your code example the following error is returned by here.exe ... `Couldn't open input file bla.txt for reading` ... however if I create a batch file `run.bat` inside `c:/myproject/betty/` where `here.exe` is located (to deliver the `-command` to here.exe) and then run your code example `process = subprocess.run('c:/myproject/betty/run.bat', env=os.environ)` ... `here.exe` executes perfectly. Do you know what could be the issue or is this the best work around option?

Comment: The same as before; you need to pass a *list* of the command name and its parameter, like my examples show.